# Firebase Auth error Cannot read property 'auth' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I've been looking for answers all over to the solution to this error. Bizarrely my code worked absolutely fine last week but doesn't today.
I want to use firebase auth to create a sign-up page for my app but I keep getting the Cannot read property 'auth' of undefined error.

firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { sendPasswordResetEmail, getAuth} from "firebase/auth";
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
// See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/learn-more#config-object
const firebaseConfig = {
               //config code
    
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);

export const sendPasswordReset = async (email) => {
    try {
      await sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email);
      alert("Password reset link sent!");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      alert(err.message);
    }
  };

export {app} ;

// // Initialize Realtime Database and get a reference to the service
// const database = getDatabase(app);
```

signupScreen.js

```
//SignupScreen.js
import {React, useState} from "react";
import { TouchableOpacity, TextInput, View, Text, Image } from "react-native";
import {styles} from "../styles/Styling";
import { acuitisLogo} from "../assets/images";
import { firebase } from "../components/firebase";


export default function SignupScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password,setPassword] = useState('');
  const [confirmPassword,setConfirmPassword] = useState('');
  const [firstName,setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [lastName,setLastName] = useState('');

  const onRegisterPress = () => {
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
        alert("Passwords don't match.")
        return
    }

    firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((response) => {
            const uid = response.user.uid
            const data = {
                id: uid,
                email,
                firstName,
                lastName,
            };
            const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users')
            usersRef
                .doc(uid)
                .set(data)
                .then(() => {
                    navigation.navigate('Home', {user: data})
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    alert(error)
                });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            alert(error)
    });
}

    return (
      <View style={ styles.stackpagecontainer }>
        {/* <Image source = {acuitisLogo} style = {{alignSelf: "center", marginTop: 100}} /> */}
        <Text style = {styles.title}> Sign up </Text>
        <View style={styles.inputView}>
          <TextInput
          style = {styles.inputButtonText}
          placeholder="First Name"
          placeholderTextColor="#949494"
          onChangeText={(firstName) => setFirstName(firstName)} />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.inputView}>
          <TextInput
          style = {styles.inputButtonText}
          placeholder="Last Name"
          placeholderTextColor="#949494"
          onChangeText={(lastName) => setLastName(lastName)} />
          </View>
        <View style={styles.inputView}>
          <TextInput
          style = {styles.inputButtonText}
          placeholder="Email"
          placeholderTextColor="#949494"
          onChangeText={(email) => setEmail(email)} />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.inputView}>
          <TextInput
          style = {styles.inputButtonText}
          placeholder="Password"
          placeholderTextColor="#949494"
          secureTextEntry={true}
          onChangeText={(password) => setPassword(password)} />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.inputView}>
          <TextInput
          style = {styles.inputButtonText}
          placeholder="Confirm Password"
          placeholderTextColor="#949494"
          secureTextEntry={true}
          onChangeText={(confirmPassword) => setConfirmPassword(confirmPassword)} />
          </View>
        <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.appButtonContainer} onPress={() => {onRegisterPress(); navigation.navigate("Login")}}>
        <Text style = {styles.appButtonText}> Submit </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>  
        <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.existingButtonContainer} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Login")}>
        <Text style = {styles.loginButtonText}> ALREADY A MEMBER? - SIGN IN HERE </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

It seems to be an issue within the "onRegisterPress" function, please help

Comment: correction: import 'firebase/compat/firestore'; is actually import 'firebase/firestore';

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch in export and import statements.

You are exporting `export {app} ;` in firebase.js

But in another file you are importing `import { firebase } from "../components/firebase";`

Comment: I've just corrected this in my code and I'm still getting the same error